# How to list all Variables of Class

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a way to list all Variables (Fields) of a class in C#.
If yes than could someone give me some examples how to save them in a `List` and get them maybe using `Anonymous Types` (var).

Comment: By "variables," do you mean fields, properties, or both?

Comment: Fields ,sory i edited my post .

Comment: _Show me the codez_... Here is the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa5z9w50.aspx

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Your question isn't perfectly clear. It sounds like you want the values of the fields for a given instance of your class:

```
var fieldValues = foo.GetType()
                     .GetFields()
                     .Select(field => field.GetValue(foo))
                     .ToList();
```

Note that `fieldValues` is `List<object>`. Here, `foo` is an existing instance of your class.

If you want `public` and non-`public` fields, you need to change the binding flags via

```
var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance |
                   BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                   BindingFlags.Public;
var fieldValues = foo.GetType()
                     .GetFields(bindingFlags)
                     .Select(field => field.GetValue(foo))
                     .ToList();
```

If you merely want the names:

```
var fieldNames = typeof(Foo).GetFields()
                            .Select(field => field.Name)
                            .ToList();
```

Here, `Foo` is the name of your class.

Comment: I get a "Expression cannot contain lambda expressions" with this syntax

Answer (score 17):

This will list the names of all fields in a class (both public and non-public, both static and instance fields):

```
BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public |
                            BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                            BindingFlags.Instance |
                            BindingFlags.Static;

foreach (FieldInfo field in typeof(TheClass).GetFields(bindingFlags))
{
    Console.WriteLine(field.Name);
}
```

If you want to get the fields based on some object instance instead, use `GetType` instead:

```
foreach (FieldInfo field in theObject.GetType().GetFields(bindingFlags))
{
    Console.WriteLine(field.Name);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Was trying to get all the enums in my class: `MyEnum enum = (MyEnum)0;`

Answer (score 8):

```
myClass.GetType().GetProperties()
```

Comment: he is asking about fields not properties.

Comment: He is asking about variables not fields.

Answer (score 4):

```
var fields = whateverYourClassType.GetType().GetFields().Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite the question asked - but here's how to get the values of all properties of type Decimal from an object called "inv":

```
var properties = inv.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (var prop in properties)
{
    if (prop.ToString().ToLower().Contains("decimal"))
    {
        totalDecimal += (Decimal)prop.GetValue(inv, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fields = yourClass.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need all properties from all subclasses as well:

```
public static List<string> getAllPropertiesFromClass(this Type type, string parent = "")
{
    BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public |
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                    BindingFlags.Instance |
                    BindingFlags.Static;
    var result = new List<string>();
    foreach (var t in type.GetFields(bindingFlags))
    {
        result.Add(parent + "." + t.Name.substringByKey("<", ">"));
        if (t.FieldType.IsClass && t.FieldType.Assembly.FullName == type.Assembly.FullName)
        {
            result.AddRange(getAllPropertiesFromClass(t.FieldType, parent + "." + t.Name.substringByKey("<", ">")));
        }
    }            
    return result;
}
public static string substringByKey(this string s, string begin, string end)
{
    if (s.IndexOf(begin) < 0)
        return "";
    var i = s.IndexOf(begin) + begin.Length;
    if (s.IndexOf(end, i) - i < 0)
        return "";
    return s.Substring(i, s.IndexOf(end, i) - i);
}
```

And call it like:

```
var names = typeof(Foo).getAllPropertiesFromClass();
```