# VB.Net datatable assign Values

Tags: vb.net

Hi I have some variables assigned with values. i need to read the variables values one by one which is in a loop and assigned them to the datatable which i have created using VB.Net.. Please help me on this..

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536163/how-to-list-all-variables-of-class

Comment: please put more info in. I can't read minds - yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a DataRow and add these to the DataTable.  If the values are in a List you can iterate through and add one at a time.  If the values are in separate values you're probably best to add each in turn.

See here for more details:

[MSDN How to: Add Rows to a DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

From this example you could use the following

```
Dim customerIds() As String= {"ALFKI", "QWERT", "ASDFG", "ZXCVB"}

For Each c As String In customerIds
    Dim newCustomersRow As DataRow = DataSet1.Tables("Customers").NewRow()
    newCustomersRow("CustomerID") = c
    DataSet1.Tables("Customers").Rows.Add(newCustomersRow)
Next

' Then call the data adapter update methode
myDataAdapter.Update(DataSet1)
```

The configuration of the DataAdapter is specific to your enviroment, but you will need a connection to the database and an InsertCommand to persist the data in the database.

Comment: Ya i need to read one by one and fill the datatable in dataset. I have a dataset DtEmployee and table Employee.. So i need to fill the datatable and then need to send the completed dataset to database...

Comment: You will need a DataAdapter to push the changes to the database.

Comment: ya i have the data adapter too.. can you pls give the piece of code to fill the table row by row by reading one by one one in a loop...

Comment: I've edited my answer and added some sample code.