# Dynamically create properties in anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, anonymous-methods

I want to create a new type using anonymous types.

This is my code:

```
 var t = paramaterList.Select(x => x).ToArray().Select(item => new
             {
                 item,
             });
```

I need to create properties for `var t` based on the name of item.

For example:

if  `paramaterList.Select(x => x).ToArray()` contained 3 items:
FirstName, Surname, Age

This should create properties for each of those items:

```
paramaterList.Select(x => x).ToArray().Select(item => new
             {

             });
```

Comment: How are you going to consume `t` if you don't know its properties at compile time?

Comment: You want too much. You know that anonymous types are compiler generated, right? Which means the answer is no, you can't do that.

Comment: Are you really looking for `dynamic` and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653046/what-are-the-true-benefits-of-expandoobject?

Comment: If not `dynamic`, then definitely an `ExpandoObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous types are still statically typed, even though they don't have a name that you can use to refer to them by.  If you don't know the fields that this object is going to have at compile time, then you can't create a variable of an anonymous type to hold that data.  You'll need to store the data in some form of data structure, such as a dictionary, that doesn't require you to know what the values are at compile time.

Comment: You can create Expression which builds anonymous type depending on properties in source type

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this? Even if I do not use anonymous types

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy But then you could never have a variable of that type.

Comment: @John Sure, store the data in a `Dictionary`, like I said in the answer.

Comment: @John You can find hundreds of thousands of examples with a quick Google search.

Comment: There is a SO question [how to list all...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536163/how-to-list-all-variables-of-class) and also use  [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)