# iterate through variables in a class c#

Tags: c#, string, class

I'm trying to get a list of all the variables in a class.  I'm trying to use reflection (which I've never used before) but it just doesn't make sense, and the docs aren't helping either.  I feel like I'm making an obvious mistake, but I can't figure it out.

```cs
        public override string ToString()
        {
            FieldInfo[] fields = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            List<string> _return = new List<string>();
            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                _return.Add(field.Name + ": " + field.GetValue(field));
            }
            return _return;
        }
```

The output is nothing.

Comment: We'll need a [mcve] to investigate further.

Comment: I'd expect `field.GetValue(field)` to throw an exception if there were any fields. It should be `field.GetValue(this)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all Variables of Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536163/how-to-list-all-variables-of-class)

Comment: @CtrlS thanks, that worked!  For some reason, that one didn't show up in my searches.

Comment: you declared public override string ToString(), but returning List<string>

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you are looking for:

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        FieldInfo[] fields = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        List<string> _return = new List<string>();
        foreach (var field in fields){
             _return.Add(field.Name + ": " + field.GetValue(this));
          }
    return string.Join(",", _return);
}
```